# case class vs case object vs object vs class vs trait vs abstract sealed isomorphism

Tags: scala

I am trying to code something similar to this: https://github.com/ornicar/scalachess/blob/master/src/main/scala/Color.scala

I have this structure:

```
sealed trait Color {
  val red = this == Color.Red
  val black = this == Color.Black
  val green = this == Color.Green
  val blue = this == Color.Blue
}

object Color {
  case object Red extends Color
  case object Black extends Color
  case object Green extends Color
  case object Blue extends Color
}
```

In the original source, `Color` types can be used like this:

`List(Red, Green, Blue)`

But in my case I have to use them like this:

`List(Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue)`

Because if I use the former it gives me this error:

`not found: value: Red`

How can I use the Color types without prefixing with `Color.`?

Comment: You can just specify `import Color._` wherever in your code you need them.

Comment: If you look at the link I gave, it doesn't have `import Color` anywhere yet it can still use it for example here: https://github.com/ornicar/scalachess/blob/master/src/test/scala/BoardTest.scala

Comment: Looking through that code base, I'm pretty sure that works because in the file package.scala (src/main/scala/package.scala) there are two fields `val White = Color.White` and `val Black = Color.Black` inside `package object chess`, which are available anywhere in the "chess" package scope.